# Pan resistance when dragging UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

some applications have this "drag resistance" when you drag an image. The further away you drag the image from the origin point, the less it becomes drag-able.
How can I implement this feature?

Comment: `UIScrollView` has this effect by default.

Comment: I guess you could do this if you set the frame or center of the UIImageView as a inverse function of distance from the original point (or a container view)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at the UISCrollView. @Rakesh, can you please provide some sources or tutorials?

Comment: @H2CO3, This answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

How about subclassing `UIImageView` and doing something like below: (Not perfect , but something along this lines maybe?)

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    CGPoint currentPosition = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    CGFloat dx = currentPosition.x  - initialCentre.x;//delta x with sign
    CGFloat dy = currentPosition.y  - initialCentre.y;//delta y with sign

    CGFloat distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);//distance

    CGFloat weightedX = initialCentre.x +  dx * (1/log(distance)); //new x as inverse function of distance
    CGFloat weightedY = initialCentre.y +  dy * (1/log(distance)); //new y as inverse function of distance

    self.center = CGPointMake(weightedX, weightedY);//set  the center


}
```